# ¿Como puedo filtrar los datos con fechas en C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

En un formulario tengo dos datetimePicker, y quiero filtrar los datos mediante las fechas de los datetimePicker, pero no me resulta ¿me puden decir en que estoy mal?. Estoy programando en modelo de tres capas, le dejo mi codigo.

CAPA DE NEGOCIOS(BUSSINESS):

```
public DataTable OEntradas(String Buscar, String FIentrada, String FFentrada)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String query = "SELECT E.SKU, S.Descripcion AS Status, E.Descripcion AS Material, U.Descripcion AS Unidad, E.Cantidad, E.Costo, P.Nombre_proveedor AS Proveedor, F.Descripcion AS Familia, E.Fecha_entrada  FROM Entradas AS E inner join status AS S ON E.Status = S.id_status inner join unidadM AS U ON E.Unidad = U.id_unidad inner join proveedores AS P ON E.Proveedor = P.id_proveedor inner join familia AS F ON E.Familia = F.id_familia WHERE E.Descripcion LIKE '%"+ Buscar +"%' AND E.Fecha_entrada BETWEEN '"+ FIentrada +"' AND '"+ FFentrada +"' ";
        dt = daccess.select(query);
        return dt;
    }
```

CAPA DE VISTA:

```
private void CGrid()
    {
        DataTable de = biss.OEntradas(txt_buscar.Text, date_entrada.Text, dateTimePicker1.Text);
        data_entradas.DataSource = de;
    }
```

asi tengo mi codigo.

Comment: La mejor forma de arreglar este tipo de error es haciendo Debug. Pon un punto de depuración (F9) en tu sentencia String query. Cuando ingrese al método coloca el puntero sobre tu dato *FIentrada* y *FFsalida* y observa si está trayendo los datos de la vista que le has pasado o si vienen NULL, así puedes determinar el error si está en la Vista o Controlador. Aperta F10 luego para pasar a la siguiente línea y pon el puntero sobre la query y observa que datos a tomado de tu sentencia. Haz la prueba y comentalo.

Comment: Posiblemente el tipo de campos que estan en tu base de datos no concuerdan con los que envias por parametros... o puede ser el formato de los mismos... cómo llega `FIentrada`? `dd-MM-yyy, yyy-MM-dd`? y también sería excelente que indicaras que tipo de dato es `Fecha_entrada` en tu BD

Comment: pues veras, el dato de fecha es tipo varchar, y cuando guardo el registro lo mando a guardar con esta sentencia: CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103))

Comment: @Macx que datos te trae al pasarle la fecha ? lo has probado si vienen las fechas o null?

Comment: prueba agregando tus campos de fecha con este formato `FIentrada.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`; obvio que incluyes lo mismo para `FFentrada`

Comment: por lo que puedo ver, creo que me arroja valores nulos, pero no me marca ningun error, amigo Paulo Urbano Rivera, tu metodo no me funciono tampoco

Comment: El formato universal en SQL Server es `yyyyMMdd`, inténtalo así.

Comment: pero la fecha la tengo guardada asi: dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: ¿hay alguna razón por la que guardas la fecha en varchar? me parece un muy mal diseño y por como puedes ver solo te trae peoblemas. Apare, la forma en que estás formando la query puede traerte problemas de inyección de datos.

Comment: no creo que el problema sea por como guardo la fecha, ya que ya pude hacer que me filtrara por fechas en los datetimepicker, ahora mi problema, es que no me filtra los datos como yo quiero, si le cambio la fecha a un solo datetimepicker solo me filtra por esa fecha, tengo que cambiarle la fecha al otro datetimepicker para que filtre por rangos, no se si me explique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque no intentar primeramente ver si te devuelven registros omitiendo esta parte de la consulta.

```
AND E.Fecha_entrada BETWEEN '"+ FIentrada +"' AND '"+ FFentrada +"' "
```

si es que devuelve intentar cambiarla por

```
AND E.Fecha_entrada >= '"+ FIentrada +"' AND "+ " E.Fecha_entrada <= '" + FFentrada +"' "
```

Comment: la sentencia la tengo como en la la primera opcion que me das y solo me arroja los encabezados de la tabla

Comment: por eso, intentaste primeramente verificar que te devuelva datos sin incluir esa linea de tu codigo? osea sin el filtro de la fecha, aveces el error esta en otra parte de la consulta.

Comment: La segunda opción que indicas se implementa con `BETWEEN` no?

Comment: No, simplemente estamos reemplazando la opcion Between por dos consultas "Mayor o igual a " y "Menor o igual a"

Comment: Por lo mismo.. `Between` ya cumple la función de filtrar entre esas dos fechas

Comment: sin la sentencia del between, si me muestra los datos, pordon no me habia fijado en la diferencia de la primer y la sengunda sentencia que me mostraste, deja checo con esa opcion que me das

Comment: no, tampoco me funciono

Comment: entonces si te devuelve datos sin el between , talvez el problema sea en el formato en el que recibe los parametros, tendrias que verificar y cambiar el formato Ej. (1900-01-31, 31-12-1900, 31/12/1900, y cosas asi), revisa que llegue el formato adecuado de una fecha. ovbiamente revisa que tengas una fecha que coincida con el rango